# Sending data to Xively using Arduino mega + GSM shield sim 900

Tags: c, xively, sim900

I want to send my sensor data to xively using GSM shield SIM900. After running my code i am getting 0 as a response from server. Please help me to figure out what's the issue? I am using rhydolabz's GSM SIM900 module with adriuno

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#include "tmp102.h"
//Please fetch tmp102.h and tmp102.cpp from "Stlker logger AM06 Serial.zip"
//available from Seeeduino Stalker v2.0's Wiki Page
#include <Wire.h>
float temp=23.65; // We then need to multiply our two bytes by a scaling factor, mentioned in the datasheet.
//int tmp102_val; // an int is capable of storing two bytes, this is where we    "chuck" the two bytes together.
SoftwareSerial GPRS_Serial(7, 8);
void setup()
{
GPRS_Serial.begin(19200); //GPRS Shield baud rate
Serial.begin(19200);
//tmp102_init();
setup_start:
Serial.println("Turn on GPRS Modem and wait for 1 minute.");
Serial.println("and then press a key");
Serial.println("Press c for power on configuration");
Serial.println("press any other key for uploading");
Serial.flush();
while(Serial.available() == 0);
if(Serial.read()=='c')
{
Serial.println("Executing AT Commands for one time power on configuration");
GPRS_Serial.flush();
GPRS_Serial.println("ATE0"); //Command echo off
Serial.println("ATE0 Sent");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(4,10) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto setup_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=0"); //We only want a single IP Connection at a time.
Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=0 Sent");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(4,10) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto setup_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIPMODE=0"); //Selecting "Normal Mode" and NOT "Transparent Mode" as the TCP/IP Application Mode
Serial.println("AT+CIPMODE=0 Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(4,10) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto setup_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CSTT=\"portalnmms\",\"\"");
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIFSR");//Defining the Packet Data
//Protocol Context - i.e. the Protocol Type, Access Point Name and IP Address
//Serial.println("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\",\"10.6.6.6\",0,0 Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(4,10) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto setup_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CSTT=\"portalnmms\",\"\""); //Start Task and set Access Point Name (and username and password if any)
Serial.println("AT+CSTT=\"portalnmms\" Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(4,10) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto setup_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIPSHUT"); //Close any GPRS Connection if open
Serial.println("AT+CIPSHUT Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(7,10) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto setup_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
}
}
void loop()
{
loop_start:
Serial.println("Press a key to read temperature and upload it");
Serial.flush();
while(Serial.available()==0);
Serial.read();
//getTemp102();
Serial.print("Temperature = ");
Serial.println(temp);
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"api.xively.com\",\"80\""); //Open a connection to Pachube.com
Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"api.xively.com\",\"80\" Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(12,255) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto loop_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.flush();
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND"); //Start data through TCP connection
Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(1,100) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto loop_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.flush();
//Emulate HTTP and use PUT command to upload temperature datapoint using Comma Seperate Value Method
GPRS_Serial.print("PUT /v2/feeds/974506916 / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
Serial.println("PUT /v2/feeds/974506916 HTTP/1.1 Sent!");
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("Host: api.xively.com\r\n");
Serial.println("Host: api.xively.com Sent!");
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("X-xivelyKey: pzjRnAI2EANrdQwaJmOUCIRJkcaKSUG7Q5xpWCAw39DAD\r\n"); //REPLACE THIS KEY WITH YOUR OWN PACHUBE API KEY
Serial.println("X-xivelyApiKey: pzjRnAI2EANrdQwaJmOUCIRJkcaKSUG7Q5xpWCAw39DAD Sent!"); //REPLACE THIS KEY WITH YOUR OWN PACHUBE API KEY
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("Content-Length: 12\r\n");
Serial.print("Content-Length: 12 Sent!");
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
Serial.print("Connection: close Sent!");
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("Temperature,"); //You may replace the stream name "TMP102" to any other string that you have choosen.
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print(temp);
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("\r\n");
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print("\r\n");
delay(300);
GPRS_Serial.print(Serial.write(0x1A));
delay(300); //Send End Of Line Character to send all the data and close connection
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(20,255) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto loop_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
GPRS_Serial.flush();
GPRS_Serial.println("AT+CIPSHUT"); //Close the GPRS Connection
Serial.println("AT+CIPSHUT Sent!");
if(GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(4,100) == 0)
{
Serial.println("Timeout");
goto loop_start;
}
else
{
Serial.print("Received:");
while(GPRS_Serial.available()!=0)
{
Serial.print((unsigned char)GPRS_Serial.read());
Serial.print("\n");
}
}
}
char GPRS_Serial_wait_for_bytes(char no_of_bytes, int timeout)
{
while(GPRS_Serial.available() < no_of_bytes)
{
delay(200);
timeout-=1;
if(timeout == 0)
{
return 0;
}
}
return 1;
}
```